# Automatically render child component when state has been updated in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

The parent component `Dashboard` holds the state for every `ListItem` I add to my `Watchlist`. Unfortunately, every time I am adding an Item, it gets added to the DB, but only shows up when I refresh the browser.

```
class UserDashboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    authService.checkAuthentication(this.props);
  }

  isLoggedIn = () => {
    return authService.authenticated()
  }

  getAllCoins = () => {
    //fetches from backend API
  }

  addWishlist = () => {
    this.getAllCoins()
      .then(things => {
        this.setState({
          data: things
        })
      })
    console.log("CHILD WAS CLICKED")
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllCoins()
      .then(things => {
        this.setState({
          data: things
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dashboard">
        <h1>HI, WELCOME TO USER DASHBOARD</h1>
        <SearchBar
          addWishlist={this.addWishlist}
        />
        <UserWatchlist
          data={this.state.data}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The User Watchlist:

```
class UserWatchlist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  // componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  //   if (this.props.data !== prevProps.data) {
  //     console.log("CURRENT", this.props.data)
  //     console.log("PREVs", prevProps.data)
  //   }
  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>These are tssssyou are watching:</h2>
        <ul className="coin-watchlist">
          {
            this.props.data.map((coin, idx) => {
              return <ListItem key={idx}
                              coin={coin.ticker}
                              price={coin.price}
                      />
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The search Bar that shows potential Items to watch over:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      coins: [],
      searchValue: ""
    }
  }


  searchHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const value = e.target.value

    this.setState({
      searchValue: value
    });

    if (value === "") {
      this.setState({
        coins: []
      })
    } else {
      this.getInfo()
    }
  }

  getInfo = () => {
    // Searches the API
  }

  addWishlist = () => {
    this.props.addWishlist();
  }

  render() {
    const {coins, searchValue} = this.state

    return (
      <div className="coin-search">
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="prompt"
            placeholder="Search by ticker symbol"
            value={searchValue}
            onChange={this.searchHandler}
          />
        </form>
        <ul className="search-suggestions">
          {
            coins.filter(searchingFor(searchValue)).map( coin =>
              <Currency
                coin={coin}
                addWishlist={this.addWishlist}
              />
            )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the actual Currency that gets clicked to be added:

```
class Currency extends React.Component {

  addToWatchlist = () => {
    // POST to backend DB to save
    };

    fetch("/api/add-coin", settings)
      .catch(err => {
        return err
      })
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    this.addToWatchlist()
    this.props.addWishlist()
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="search-results">
          <li>
            <h3> { this.props.coin.currency } </h3>
            <button
              className="add-to-list"
              onClick={this.clickHandler}
              >
                + to Watchlist
              </button>
          </li>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am sending props down all the way down to child. When I click the button to Add to Watchlist, I see the console.log message appear, saying "CHILD WAS CLICKED". I've even tried just calling the method to fetch from backend API again.

Also, in UserWatchlist, I've tried a componentDidUpdate, but both prevProps and this.props show the very same array of data. Somewhere in the chain, my data is getting lost.

This is also my first time posting a question here, so if it can be improved, I am happy to add extra details and contribute something to this community

Comment: can you provide codesandbox for this?

Comment: is `getAllCoin()` actually returning a promise? I'm seeing you calling a `.then()` on that method and maybe your getAllCoin method isn't returning a promise and that may be why your setState isn't getting called. Try console log something as the second argument for your setState, and let me know if console.log gets called.

Comment: @mxdi9i7 Yes, it returns the API call (within a separate helper file) and I do see the results as a part of componentDidMount(). Seems like when I try re running the function from within addWishlist(), it doesn't happen. Then again, maybe I shouldn't be making two calls like that (is it bad design?)

Comment: Did you try console logging something as the callback of setState? `this.setState({data:thing}, console.log('ping'))`

Comment: @mxdi9i7 sorry, was at work. But, I just tried this:

```addWishlist = () => {
    this.getAllCoins()
      .then(things => {
        this.setState({
          data: things
        })
      }, console.log("PING"))
  }```

I see the PING in the console after the "add" action, but I still need to refresh the browser

Comment: Try `this.forceUpdate()` after you update state?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to wait for addToWatchlist to complete:

```
  addToWatchlist = () => {
    // POST to backend DB to save
    return fetch("/api/add-coin", settings)
      .catch(err => {
        return err
      })
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    this.addToWatchlist().then(() => {
      this.props.addWishlist()
    })
  }
```

Comment: Trying that, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. addToWatchlist is completing; I can see console.log statements happening during events